# Grid Search for Polynomial Kernel

Tags: svm

I am trying to do a grid search for a polynomial kernel. I have used the normal grid search on polynomial kernels which is wrong. I only varied $c$ and $\gamma$... but I need to vary $a$ and $b$... Is there any fast method to do grid search for polynomial kernels?

Polynomial kernel: $K(x_i, x_j) = (\gamma x_i x_j + a)^b,\quad \gamma > 0$

Any suggestions or any corrections as well are welcome.

Comment: What is *c*? There's no *c* in your equation.

Comment: C is the amount of misclassification.... it is for all kernels...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I woud recommend a grid search over integer values of b, and for each value of b perform a search for C, gamma and a using the [Nelder-Mead simplex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method), which is a standard numerical optimiser that does not rely on gradient information and works fairly well (it is the fminsearch function in MATLAB).

Comment: I have one suggestion, not sure whether correct or wrong? Why don't u find the best value for c and gamma first, then with that value, try different values for b?

Comment: changing b changes the kernel induced feature space, you you can expect it to change the optimal value of the other hyper-parameters as well as they are often correlated.

Comment: if you show an example fo fminsearch using MATLAB, it would be really useful... thanks...

Comment: Without being familiar with the SVM package you are using I can't give any better information than the fminsearch help message.  I use my own matlab software, which has model selection built in, but unfortunately has no manual, see http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/projects/gkm/

Comment: i am using libsvm...

Comment: I'm afraid I have not used libsvm, so I can't be much help there.  I'm sure if you experiment with fminsearch to optimise a few simple functions, such as Rosenblocks' banana http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function you will be able to see how to use it for tuning SVMs.